# About Frobenius's theorem for differential forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-forms

My question is about a particular case of Frobenius's theorem that states the complete integrability condition for a Pfaff system. Namely,
when dealing with a system reduced to a single 1-form, the statement takes the following form:
Let $v$ be a smooth 1-form nowhere vanishing on an open subset of $R^n$ (or more generally on a smooth manifold); the following conditions are equivalent:

(i) $v \wedge dv = 0$.

(ii) Locally, there is a 1-form $\sigma$ such that $dv = v \wedge \sigma$.

(iii) Locally, there are two functions $f,h$ such that $v = h df$.

The equivalence between (i) and (ii) is very simple and essentially algebraic: For (ii)$\Rightarrow$(i), we have $v\wedge dv = v\wedge v\wedge \sigma =0$; for (i)$\Rightarrow$(ii), take some coordinate system $(x^1,...,x^n)$ such that $(v,dx^2,...,dx^n)$ forms a basis of the space of 1-forms, express $dv$ in the basis of the space of 2-forms, given by $v\wedge dx^i (2\le i\le n)$ and  $dx^i\wedge dx^j (2\le i<j\le n)$, and write the condition $v\wedge dv=0$.

Condition (iii) is the statement of integrability. The equivalence between (i) and (iii) is often referred to as Frobenius's theorem in textbooks on general relativity. The implication (iii)$\Rightarrow$(ii) is again trivial and purely algebraic: if (iii) is true one has $dv=v\wedge \sigma$ with $\sigma=-dh/h$. The implication (ii)$\Rightarrow$(iii), on the other hand, involves analysis in an essential way, via the theory of existence and uniqueness for a completely integrable system of PDEs (that is, Frobenius theorem). This is done nicely for example in Dieudonné's Analysis, vols I and IV.

Still, I am wondering if this last implication cannot be proven "more" algebraically. This would entail for example the following:
Chose coordinates $(x^1,...,x^n)$ such that $(v,dx^2,...,dx^n)$ is a basis of 1-forms. Then we have $v=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i dx^i=v_1\omega$, where $\omega=dx^1-\sum_{i=2}^n\beta_i dx^i, \beta_i=-v_i/v_1$. Using (ii) prove, algebraically, that $\omega$ is closed (i.e. $d\omega=0$), hence locally exact.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the details of the last step?

Comment: I believe this is counterexample to your attempted approach: take $\nu=dx_1+x_1dx_2$. Then $\nu_1=1$ and $\omega=\nu$.

Comment: Here you can read a proof without using Lie brackets i.e. just using differential forms: http://joelshapiro.org/Pubvit/Downloads/Frobenius_RLyons.pdf                                                                                   to be more precise: put $p = m-1$ in Theorem 3.2.1. at page 23 and follow the proof. Actually, it seems to me that the proof is somehow similar to Problem 3, Section 18.16 in Dieudonné's Analysis IV.

Comment: May thanks for the above comments. Clearly Michael is right, and I was (by far) overly optimistic: for the form $v=dx_1+x_1dx_2$ we have $dv=dx_1\wedge dx_2\neq 0$ and $v\wedge dv=0$, so this is a counterexample. In this case we have $v=hdf$ with $f=x_1e^{x_2}$ and $h=e^{-x_2}$.

Comment: In any case you can avoid Frobenius Theorem by using a version of Darboux Theorem. Namely, you can apply Darboux theorem to the exact two form $dv$ to get a canonical form and then show $ii)$ implies $iii)$.